# $compile is affecting all directive elements

Tags: angularjs

I am prepending elements into the DOM and giving them position expressions from the parent controller. As each new one is added the position element is updated on all existing elements on the DOM. I only want it to update the position on the new directive element.

```
   .directive("addbuttons",
     function($compile, PositionService, $timeout){
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         replace: false,
         scope: {
          test: "@"
          },
          link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {

      $timeout(function () {

        var posX = 0, posY = 0;
        ionic.onGesture('tap', function (e) {
          e.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault();
          e.gesture.preventDefault();
          switch (e.type) {
            case 'tap':
              posX = event.gesture.touches[0].pageX;
              posY = event.gesture.touches[0].pageY;
              //$scope.test = posX;
              //console.log(posX);
              console.log(posY);
              break;
          }
        }, $element[0]);
      });
      $element.bind("click", function () {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('tagContainer')).prepend($compile("<div class='square' id='square1' style='left: {{test}}px' data-ion-pinch></div>")($scope));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Think you could greatly simplify this code with ng-click and ng-style, rather than using $compile

Answer (score 0):

You are going againts AngularJS patterns. Just use the default directives such as `ng-click`, `ng-class`. Remember, always try to leave DOM manipulation to Angular, you should "only" manage the model (as long as you can).

Comment: So how would I put a css position to an element I am prepending to the DOM